# List of devices connected to hotspot on Android 13

Tags: java, android, hotspot

I am working on an android app that based on java that need the list of devices connected to hotspot which has been using arp table and ip neigh command. In the target SDK version 33, arp table and ip neigh are both not working. My app will need the IP and MAC Address of the devices while pinging the subnet mask can only know the IP Address of the devices.

```
                BufferedReader br = null;
                List<String> args = new ArrayList<String> ();
                args.add("ip");
                args.add("neigh");
                String args = listOf("ip", "neigh");
                ProcessBuilder cmd = new ProcessBuilder(args);
                Process process = cmd.start();
                br = new BufferedReader(new 
                InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
                String line;

                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println("line="+line.toString()); }

                BufferedReader errReader = new BufferedReader(new 
                InputStreamReader(process.getErrorStream()));
                br.close();
                errReader.close();
                process.destroy();
```

Is there any alternative to get the list of devices connected to hotspot without root?

Comment: Please include the code which you have tried.

Comment: @wolf added the code for ip neigh, actually there is nothing wrong in the code. The problem is i need an alternative to get the device list in target SDK version 33